# nginx - how to block custom headers

Tags: nginx, http-headers, security

I have `nginx` running locally, alongside my local test `SOAP server`. I am using `SoapUI` to send soap requests to this server via nginx, eg `SoapUI -> Nginx:80 -> SoapSever:9338`.

My goal is to strip out non-standard headers, to tighten up security. I want to keep `content-type`, `accept`, etc, but  I want to strip headers such as `myHeader1`, or `abc=xyz`.

As part of my testing, I am sending custom headers, and I can see them arriving at my server on the far side, so nginx isnt doing any filtering. I tried using `ignore_invalid_headers on;` in my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file under `http {}`, but I think it means something different to what I think it means, as it doesnt strip any headers.

I can see from the docs that you can add headers, or change specific headers, but can I either strip out all non-standard/custom headers, or can I specify a list of headers that I only want to accept?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ignore_invalid_headers` directive only ignores headers which are wrongly formatted.
To clear certain headers you could have a look at the `more_clear_headers` directive.

See http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHeadersMoreModule#more_clear_headers for more details.

**It's not part of the standard nginx distribution so you will have to install it manually.**

*Example*

```
more_clear_headers 'X-*';
```

Will clear all headers starting with `X-`

Comment: Thanks. So you're saying I can't filter these headers without an addon? If I install that addon, is it possible to filter all headers except a specified few? Because `X-*` wont block `header` or `headerXYZ` or whatever a hacker decided to make up.

Comment: Yes you need the addon. It still doesn't provide the exact functionality that you wan't but it's the closest thing. You could also write your own addon if you're up for it. http://wiki.nginx.org/3rdPartyModules#Tools_for_module_developers

Comment: I found an old github repo that tried to do similar. But I've no idea if it works: https://github.com/localshred/nginx-whitelist

Comment: Looks hopeful! But I wouldn't know if it works either. If you want to dive deep then here is an article about developing modules. It also covers building. http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html